# Handling redirect code with OAuth2

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, authorization, instagram-api

I am using Instagram's API which requires OAuth2 have some questions regarding best practice for setup. For more details here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

So a user clicks on a login button and I give a redirect href.

```
<a href="instagram redirect...">Log In</a>
```

They then receive a popup sign in, and they have the option of signing in or not. They are then redirected and '?code=zzzzzzz'is appended to the url: "http://localhost:8080?code=zzzzzzz"

Then the instructions read:

---

Now you need to exchange the code you have received in the previous step for an access token. In order to make this exchange, you simply have to POST this code, along with some app identification parameters, to our access_token endpoint.

---

But how should I do this? I'm using Express on the backend. To serve the frontend I use this line:

```
var static_path = path.join(__dirname, './../build');
```

It isn't an API route, so I can't use the normal

```
app.get('/?code=zzzzzzz', function(req, res) {...}).
```

So how can I use the code that I received in the params?

Comment: Did you solved this?

Answer (score -1):

You must change your redirect_uri on isntagram to something like:

```
/auth/instagram/callback


https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/auth/instagram/callback&response_type=code
```

Then you can get your code with req.query.code from inside the controller.
For posting the code to isntagrams API use "request" library for nodejs